# Automatically click also 2nd button when click 1st button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem in the click buttons. What i need is to automatically clicked 2nd button when i click the 1st button.. I have created a sample code which is not working

HTML

```
<button id="button1" class="btn btn-success">1st button</button>
<a id="button2" class="btn btn-success" href="google.com">2nd button</a>
```

jQuery

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#button1').click(function () {
      jQuery('#button2').click();
   })
   });
```

Here's my jdfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/wj8pb9sf/

Comment: this code seems fine, change the link to `https://www.google.com/`

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed didnt work

Answer (score 1):

I've had this code snippet for quite some time and it has proven itself to be very valuable in these situations:

```
// Simulate event
function fireEvent(node, eventName) {
    // Make sure we use the ownerDocument from the provided node to avoid cross-window problems
    var doc;
    if (node.ownerDocument) {
        doc = node.ownerDocument;
    } else if (node.nodeType == 9){
        // the node may be the document itself, nodeType 9 = DOCUMENT_NODE
        doc = node;
    } else {
        throw new Error("Invalid node passed to fireEvent: " + node.id);
    }

    if (node.dispatchEvent) {
        // Gecko-style approach (now the standard) takes more work
        var eventClass = "";

        // Different events have different event classes.
        // If this switch statement can't map an eventName to an eventClass,
        // the event firing is going to fail.
        switch (eventName) {
            case "click": // Dispatching of 'click' appears to not work correctly in Safari. Use 'mousedown' or 'mouseup' instead.
            case "mousedown":
            case "mouseup":
                eventClass = "MouseEvents";
                break;

            case "focus":
            case "change":
            case "blur":
            case "select":
                eventClass = "HTMLEvents";
                break;

            default:
                throw "fireEvent: Couldn't find an event class for event '" + eventName + "'.";
                break;
        }
        var event = doc.createEvent(eventClass);
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, true); // All events created as bubbling and cancelable.

        event.synthetic = true; // allow detection of synthetic events
        // The second parameter says go ahead with the default action
        node.dispatchEvent(event, true);
    } else  if (node.fireEvent) {
        // IE-old school style, you can drop this if you don't need to support IE8 and lower
        var event = doc.createEventObject();
        event.synthetic = true; // allow detection of synthetic events
        node.fireEvent("on" + eventName, event);
    }
};
```

It doesn't rely on jQuery and allowes you to simulate a bunch of usefull events. Simply do: `fireEvent(document.getElementById('button2'), 'click');`.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#button2").click();
});`

And also you can't give `href` in button.

Comment: Nice one on the `href` attribute. I even missed that one, lol

Comment: @RanjithKumar i have edited the code from the top.. hopefully someone will make some jsfiddle for it

Comment: @RheaLorraine Click 2nd button will it take to that link?

Comment: @RanjithKumar no. click the first button and will take to the link from 2nd button.. Obviosly if i click the 2nd button it will take to the link, but what i want is to click 1st button and take to link from 2nd button.  i have created a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wj8pb9sf/

Comment: @RheaLorraine I am just checking

Comment: @RheaLorraine It's an oddity in jQuery. It's actually triggering the click perfectly fine. It just doesn't follow the hyperlink. Hence I gave you the pure JS solution. Check out this fiddle as a proof of concept and make sure you open up your browser's console (F12): [https://jsfiddle.net/76t5kbmw/](https://jsfiddle.net/76t5kbmw/)

Comment: @RheaLorraine Could you try this or else some different? ` 
   $('#button1').click(function () {
       window.location.href='https://www.google.com';
   }); `